# Quill and Vue 3 Typescript - quill Cannot import themes/snow. Are you sure it was registered?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, quill

I am trying to get started with the [Quill rich text editor](https://github.com/vueup/vue-quill) in my Vue 3 Typescript project.  I have added the following lines to register the `QuillEditor` component:

```
import { QuillEditor } from "@vueup/vue-quill";
import "@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css";

<snip>
export default defineComponent({
  name: "dev-ask",
  components: {
    QuillEditor,
  },
<snip>
```

...and I'm using my component in my page:

```
<QuillEditor theme="snow" />
```

However, when I view the page I get an error in the console saying:

```
quill Cannot import themes/snow. Are you sure it was registered?
```

The page never renders properly and that's the primary error message I see.  What am I doing wrong here?  I'm following the usage directions I found [here](https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/guide/usage.html#in-single-file-component).  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The module `@vueup/vue-quill` still appears to be in early development. I wasn't able to get it working through their guide either. However, I played around with various methods of importing and I was able to get a working scenario in the Vue SFC Playground.

See [working example here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__DEV__eNqdkU9PwkAQxb/Kuhc0sbt4tBaCBxOvevGyF2gHKO4/d6cQ0vS7O1sgNJAYQw9N38zk915nWv7qvdg2wHNexDLUHlkEbPxU2dp4F5C1LMCSdWwZnGEjGh0NWh9NrfVbVaMLpxHFZzTUeEnv7Cf1FVdW2dLZiMzEFZsk4v3oHbR27MsFXd3RM3pQtpCHDOROAsF4PUcgxVjRozI4eG0z4yrQOUERLE4UJ7Di7Kgz3Hug4hoNuTNcg0kyWrdTfFrIIetA99NPiI3GnBUlkadt20ftukL2upBpJYUcZCIZca/T5+y4kOSIPuZSNtZ/r0TpjLzcxuxJjMU4WwDOxbOs6ojnnkgJRRmj4i/9Nno+f+QHfmbmXmyis3StNsVWxwbN56yvpBrhkj6Hicsy3XgThQur5CZCY7E2ICCabBHcLkIgsOKPJ8b1DYfAG//u327yNrsBkSYk2WwhZAFsBQHCXzu5GL1KmrCdsh3vfgHgRBw9).

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { QuillEditor } from "@vueup/vue-quill"

const msg = ref('Hello World!!!!')
</script>

<template>
  <quill-editor v-model:content="msg" content-type="html" theme="snow"></quill-editor>
  <p>Result: <code>{{ msg }}</code></p>
</template>

<style>
@import "https://unpkg.com/@vueup/vue-quill@1.0.0-beta.9/dist/vue-quill.snow.css";
</style>
```

The main difference is that instead of importing the CSS in the script tag, it's being imported in the style tag. This might just be a side-effect of the SFC Playground and you may be able to import it with just a `<style src="@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css"></style>` in the component file.

It would also seem that the default "latest" version of `@vueup/vue-quill` is currently still `1.0.0-alpha.1`, even though a more recent beta version is available (currently `1.0.0-beta.9`), which I've opted to use in the linked example above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing the package with:

```
npm install @vueup/vue-quill
```

Solution was to use:

```
npm install @vueup/vue-quill@beta --save
```